# SQL Export Tool

Tags: sql

I currently have some SQL code that I am running in Excel to retrieve some data from a database. However, Excel crashes every time I run it. However, I know the code does work, because a colleague was able to use SQL Oracle Developer to export the data in about 30 seconds.

I want to be able to run the SQL code and get the data for myself but I am not permitted to have SQL Oracle Developer because of security issues (I presume there is a risk I may accidentally corrupt the database).

So my question is whether there is other software/method to export the data using the SQL without have the security issue I mentioned above?

I look forward to hearing from you all.

Jim

Comment: Sorry, not a question for SO.

Comment: Can you expand please?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Sounds like you need to talk to your security folks and DBAs to ask them for access to whatever database you're running the query on and temporary admin rights to install a sql client on your pc.

Comment: Well I have described the problem already - Excel hangs when I try to run the SQL code. I have tried to solve the problem by asking permission to have SQL Oracle Developer installed which was denied.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) are you using? Postgres? Oracle? And which tool do you use to "run the SQL"?

Comment: Sorry Tommy O - what is DBAs? Database Administrators? What is a SQL client? I know the SQL code has worked previously to extract data, but for some unknown reason it has recently become unresponsive!

Comment: Thank you a_horse_with_no_name. I am using ODBC to connect I believe. Does that make sense?

Comment: 1. add the SQL you are using **include the ODBC connection string** `2. add the error message you get from Excel` 3.is your friend able to run your Excel based query without error? `Edit the question with this detail` (improve the question without adding comments and it might be answerable).

Comment: Thanks for your input